# CoxPH with one ID contributing many comparator observations

Tags: r, survival, bootstrap, cox-model, epidemiology

UPDATE-----------------

I have data where one ID can serve as a comparator several times.

This is done by creating a variable to group the treated in variable `GROUP`. Assume variable `GROUP`, as an example, containing the number of visits to a physician until a therapy is initiated. Thus, `ID` 4 initiated the therapy after 3 visits. A possible comparator is selected if it also has 3 physician visits but does not initiate the therapy. Therefore, both belong to `GROUP == 3`. Note that this could happen on different points in time specified in variable `TIME_POINT`. As `ID` 1 never starts therapy it contributes also a possible comparator observation for someone who initiated therapy after 5 physician visits in `GROUP == 5`.
Next, within every value of variable `GROUP`, the covariates are collected in a time window before the `TIME_POINT` on which an `ID` belongs to a `GROUP`.
In this minimum example, assume covariates to be balanced using a weight specified in variable `WEIGHT`. In addition, the data outside the minimum example has several comparators per `GROUP`.

Kept short:
`ID` 1 is a comparator as it is untreated (`TREAT == 0`) and has one event in total.
`ID` 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 are different from each other and were treated (`TREAT == 1`).

`ID` 1 therefore contributes to different `GROUP`s as a comparator for `ID` 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

`ID` 1 has one event in total.
Accordingly, the duration of the follow-up time (Variable `FOLLOW_UP_TIME`) naturally shortens as value of `GROUP` and the associated variable `TIME_POINT` increases.

Data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  TREAT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  GROUP = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  TIME_POINT = as.Date(c("2019-05-13", "2019-06-01", "2020-03-01", "2021-02-01", "2022-09-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-04-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-01-13", "2021-01-01")),
  EVENT_DATE = as.Date(c("2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-01-03", "2021-10-03", NA, NA, NA)),
  END_DATE = as.Date(c("2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-01-03", "2022-10-03", "2021-10-04", "2021-09-03", "2021-11-02")),
  EVENT = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  FOLLOW_UP_TIME = c(1237, 1218, 944, 607, 30, 336, 185, 95, 233, 305),
  WEIGHT = c(0.834, 0.543, 0.234, 0.743, 0.323, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

```
ID TREAT GROUP TIME_POINT EVENT_DATE   END_DATE EVENT FOLLOW_UP_TIME WEIGHT

1     0     1 2019-05-13 2022-10-01 2022-10-01  1     1237            0.834
1     0     2 2019-06-01 2022-10-01 2022-10-01  1     1218            0.543
1     0     3 2020-03-01 2022-10-01 2022-10-01  1     944             0.234
1     0     4 2021-02-01 2022-10-01 2022-10-01  1     607             0.743
1     0     5 2022-09-01 2022-10-01 2022-10-01  1     30              0.323


2     1     1 2021-02-01 2022-01-03 2022-01-03  1     336                1
3     1     2 2021-04-01 2021-10-03 2021-10-03  1     185                1
4     1     3 2021-07-01       <NA> 2021-10-04  0     95                 1
5     1     4 2021-01-13       <NA> 2021-09-03  0     233                1
6     1     5 2021-01-01       <NA> 2021-11-02  0     305                1
```

Example of `GROUP == 5`:

```
ID TREAT GROUP TIME_POINT EVENT_DATE   END_DATE EVENT FOLLOW_UP_TIME WEIGHT
1     0     5 2022-09-01 2022-10-01 2022-10-01  1     30              0.323
6     1     5 2021-01-01       <NA> 2021-11-02  0     305                1
```

Since an ID can occur several times as a comparator, I use bootstrapped standard errors for the cox model and tried to specify the cluster argument to account for the different time points of comparability, specified in variable `GROUP`:

```
library(survival)
library(boot)

r <- 1000

cox_fit <- function(data, indices) {
  subset_data <- data[indices, ]
  cox_model <- coxph(Surv(FOLLOW_UP_TIME, EVENT) ~ TREAT, data = subset_data, robust = TRUE, weights = WEIGHT, cluster = GROUP)
  return(coef(cox_model))
}

set.seed(123)
bootstrap_results <- boot(data = data, statistic = cox_fit, R = r)
print(bootstrap_results, digits = 2)

conf_level <- 0.95
boot_ci <- boot.ci(bootstrap_results, type = c("bca"), conf = conf_level)
boot_ci
```

Model:

```
ph <- coxph(Surv(FOLLOW_UP_TIME, EVENT) ~ TREAT, data = data, robust = TRUE, weights = WEIGHT, cluster = GROUP)

> ph
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(FOLLOW_UP_TIME, EVENT) ~ TREAT, data = data, 
    weights = WEIGHT, robust = TRUE, cluster = GROUP)

       coef exp(coef) se(coef) robust se    z     p
TREAT 2.053     7.792    1.950     1.396 1.47 0.141

Likelihood ratio test=1.58  on 1 df, p=0.2088
n= 10, number of events= 7
```

Is the cluster argument sufficient? How to handle such situation where one contributes many times as a comparator since the model assumes 7 events?

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about the nature of the `TIME_POINT` variable and its relation to `FOLLOW_UP_TIME`. The definition of `GROUP` based on `TIME_POINT` seems a bit unusual. If you are trying to correct for `TIME_POINT` as something like a study-entry time, that might be better handled with `TIME_POINT` as a predictor in the model. Also, do you only have 6 individuals with 3 events among them? Or is this just a set of sample data illustrating the situation?

Comment: The data is only a minimum example. Basically, there are several comparators for someone who has `treat == 1`. 
Variable `GROUP` must be used because, for example, 2 `ID`s can also have different `TIME_POINTS` but belong to the same `GROUP`. Due to the complexity, however, I have left this out.

Comment: @EdM Variable `FOLLOW_UP_TIME` is the difference between `TIME_POINT` and `EVENT_DATE`

Comment: It would help if you could edit the question to provide some examples for things like "2 `ID`s can also have different `TIME_POINTS` but belong to the same `GROUP`." If I understand correctly, `GROUP` is a categorization according to `TIME_POINT` values; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500) for why that's a bad idea. There are better ways to adjust for differences in `TIME_POINT` values, if that's what you want to do. Please provide that information and what's in your previous comments by editing the original question; comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM Thank you very much for your feedback. I hope it is more clearly now.

Answer (score 2):

Your design of the `GROUP` variable troubles me.

> Assume variable `GROUP`, as an example, containing the number of visits to a physician until a therapy is initiated.

In that formulation, your `ID1` case has a *right-censored* value for `GROUP`. It would have been *at least* 5 visits, and might have been more if the event hadn't already happened.

That also leads to the uncomfortable situation of having 5 different `FOLLOW_UP_TIME` values for the same individual. The `Surv(FOLLOW_UP_TIME, EVENT)` formula depends on a consistent choice of `time = 0`. In this situation that might be the time from study entry or the time when therapy began, but there should only be a single `time = 0` reference for each individual.

The setup in the OP thus seems to be inconsistent. It seems to use the time when therapy began as the `time = 0` reference for those who started therapy, but the date of study entry (first visit) for `ID1` who never started therapy, at least in the first data row. That could lead to substantial bias.

A modification of the counting-process Cox model with `Surv(start_time, stop_time, status)` proposed by Lukas Lohse would be a way to handle this, if you wanted to use the date of study entry as the `time = 0` reference. You would then define a row with `(start_time, stop_time, status)` for each individual for each interval between visits. The `status` would then be the status at the end of that time interval. One way to handle the initiation of therapy would be to add an indicator of whether therapy had begun at the start of the interval to each row, as a time-varying covariate. For `ID1` that indicator of therapy would always be 0; for others, it would be zero for all intervals until the one at which therapy began. Other ways to represent therapy over time might be considered.

If you want to use the date of starting therapy as a reference, you could use the `GROUP` indicator variable to represent the number of visits before therapy was begun and the `Surv(FOLLOW_UP_TIME, EVENT)` Cox model form. But then you should not include individuals like `ID1` who never started therapy. Your model would then be conditional upon having started therapy.

I sense additional problems with the design, as the choice of when to start therapy presumably represents an estimate of current disease status. Then the number of visits prior to therapy is perhaps just a measure of how early in the disease process an individual was first seen. You should try to get some experienced local statistical advice to help work through the possible sources of bias in this study and how best to formulate and text your hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you soooo much for your comprehensive answer. IDs with TREAT == 0 never initiate therapy. The variable GROUP just functions to „find the point of comparability“  - you can think of IDs who belong to one GROUP having approximately the same „disease intensity“.

Comment: @geek45 that doesn't deal with the inconsistency in defining the `time = 0` reference. If that is time at study entry, you can't use the _future_ number of visits until therapy starts as a predictor, as that looks into the future and violates causality. You would need some other measure of disease severity that's available at study entry. If the `time = 0` reference is the start of therapy, then individuals like `ID1` can't be modeled. And you certainly do not want a whole set of different survival times for the same individual if there is at most one event per individual.

Comment: @geek45 if you want to use time at study entry as `time = 0` and don't have a measure of disease severity that is available at that time, you need to treat therapy as a time-varying covariate in some way.

Answer (score 1):

@EdM has good points in his  comments and I would also question, that if `TIME_POINT` is study entry, them it can't really change for ID-1. But if I accept for a moment, then `GROUP` seems a straight forward example of a time dependent covariate, see here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf

The key inside here is that ID 1 was in group 1 not for 365 days but only for January 2021 and it didn't have the event while in group 5 but when it was in group 1. To implement this we need to use the `start`, `stop` `Surv`-notation

```r
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)

dat_surv <- data %>%  
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(ID, TIME_POINT) %>% 
  mutate(start_time = TIME_POINT - min(TIME_POINT)) %>% # min stays in group defined by group_by
  mutate(stop_time = pmin(END_DATE - min(TIME_POINT), lead(start_time), na.rm = T)) %>% # lead stays in group, pmin is rowwise
  mutate(status = (EVENT == 1) & (TIME_POINT == max(TIME_POINT))) # only timeframe with event is marked



# unsuprisingly the minimal example with 3 events does not work well       
ph <- coxph(Surv(start_time, stop_time, status) ~ TREAT, data = dat_surv, robust = TRUE, weights = WEIGHT, cluster = GROUP)
summary(ph)
```

transformed data:

```r
> dat_surv %>%  select(ID, TIME_POINT,start_time, stop_time, status)
# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Groups:   ID [6]
      ID TIME_POINT start_time stop_time status
   <dbl> <date>     <drtn>     <drtn>    <lgl> 
 1     1 2021-01-01   0 days    31 days  FALSE 
 2     1 2021-02-01  31 days    59 days  FALSE 
 3     1 2021-03-01  59 days    90 days  FALSE 
 4     1 2021-04-01  90 days   120 days  FALSE 
 5     1 2021-05-01 120 days   365 days  TRUE  
 6     2 2021-05-01   0 days   247 days  TRUE  
 7     3 2021-04-01   0 days   246 days  TRUE  
 8     4 2021-03-01   0 days   217 days  FALSE 
 9     5 2021-02-01   0 days   214 days  FALSE 
10     6 2021-01-01   0 days   305 days  FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I have updated the question. Hope that it is more precise now.